# PHP include_once multiple and with different variables?

Tags: php, for-loop, include

First of all, I really do not know what title I should have given to this question.

Here is how far I got:

```
<?php 
$number = 50; 
for($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
$variable_for_include = 'something'.$i;
echo '<div id="1x';
echo "$i";
echo '">';
include_once '/include.php';
echo "</div>";
}  
?>
<
```

What I want it to do.

It should create:

```
<div id="1x1"> include file content 1 </div> 
...
<div id="1x50"> include file content 50 </div>
```

The include files needs a variable. Here called `$variable_for_include`.
Because from `<div id="1x1"> to <div id="1x50">` the include should output different data.

I know the question might be confusing because I am a newby and really can't express myself.
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: From the php docs for include_once:

if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. 

Other then that, the code looks fine. What problems are you having?

Comment: But I want it to include it again but with different content. The content of include.php depending on the variable $variable_for_include

Comment: But if I do this then there is an endless loop

Comment: If that is the case, then the issue is the contents of include.php. This code is fine.

Comment: You are doing something extremely strange an unusual. And it is apparently not the way to go. Any reason you don't want to place the code itself inside of the loop, without includes?

Comment: Endless loop? Who said you that? Can you post the include file contents?

Comment: The code is really big. And I want to do this more than once. But I also think that I am doing something really strange...

Comment: if the code is really big, put it in a function in your main file instead of a completely seperate php file. Then you can just call the function instead of messing with includes.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, `include_once` actually includes the file **once** :) 
Try to use `include`. 
Or maybe you should have different files if there are just few cases.
Also you can have one include with one big function. You'll include the file outside the loop, and call the function every time with different variables inside the loop. Something like this:

```
<?php 
$number = 50; 
include_once '/include.php';
for($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {
$variable_for_include = 'something'.$i;
echo '<div id="1x';
echo "$i";
echo '">';
functionFromIncldedFile($variable_for_include);
echo "</div>";
}  
?>
```

Comment: functionFromIncldedFile() how can I make a function out of the included file? - sorry newby

Comment: just enclose all your content in include file in that function. Something like this:
`<?php function functionFromIncldedFile($var){ ... } ?>`

Comment: inside function body is your code you have in the file before.

Comment: Well as I said this did not work for me but it gave me the hint I needed. I modified it for my needs and now it works. So Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `include` instead of `include_once` and the file will be included in every loop.

Comment: Yes but then I get an endless loop.

Comment: How does your `include.php` look like? Is `$i` manipulated in there? That might cause the endless loop.

Comment: Yes $i is manipulated in there because of the way the variable $variable_for_include is defined. But I want that every div has a different content...